# Non ownership of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, ownership

I have a vector of teams, the home team and the away team which are created as a `unique_ptr` as the `match` should own both teams and destroyed as the `Match` is destroyed.

I've read a number of articles and watched a number of talks around both `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` and the key seems to be *ownership*.

I have both teams held within a `vector` as such:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Team> > m_pTeams{}; // Match.hpp
```

Is it acceptable to have "helper" variables that reference both like so?

```
const Team* m_pHome{}; // Match.hpp
const Team* m_pAway{}; // Match.hpp

m_pHome = m_pTeams[0].get(); // CreateTeams() within Match.cpp
m_pAway = m_pTeams[1].get(); // CreateTeams() within Match.cpp
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using raw pointers. Only that you need to make sure they aren't used after the original objects were destroyed - and raw pointers don't possed such information.

Comment: Is polymorphism involved?  If not, you don't need the pointer at all and just have `vector<Team>`.

Comment: @Eljay That's a good point - I'm a newbie to C++, so trying to learn pointers and probably using them incorrectly. There won't be, as a Team is the base class and nothing can come off that in this. So presumably you'd take the approach as you say and then have the two helper variables (const raw pointers)?

Comment: I'd have `auto Home() -> Team& { return m_Teams[0]; }` and `auto Away() -> Team& { return m_Teams[1]; }` helper member functions.

Comment: For that matter, it's not clear why you want a vector of exactly two elements. Why not simply two member variables, `Team m_home` and `Team m_away`?

Comment: That said, it's odd that `Match` owns the two `Team`s. In the real world, teams aren't usually assembled just for one match and disbanded afterwards

Comment: @Eljay if the number of elements in `std::vector` does not change after the raw pointer is retrieved then this is true. Otherwise `std::unique_ptr` would be still a valid choice. Or `std::list` instead of `std::vector` should be used, because that would minimize the risk that you forget about that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having helper variables. You must be careful about object's lifetime.

Assuming that `Match` objects can return `Team` objects - one consideration to make is to return a reference instead of a pointer. This would prevent any misuse regarding creation and deletion of `Team` outside of `Match`.

Otherwise your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you decide to use smart pointer in your project, then you should design it in a way that the raw pointers are always not owning pointers. If you work with 3rd party libraries that return owning pointers you then should need to think about a wrapping strategy for those and document that well. Wrapping could - depending on how the library functions claim ownership over that pointer again - be smart pointers with a custom destructor or a custom wrapper. So when using smart pointer you should have the release of resource like `delete` only in special places in the code.